# Identify movie with a lost man being guided by a helpline operator

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for someone to help me identify this movie:
I believe it's about 9 years old. The movie revolves around a business man who gets lost on his way to a meeting. He realizes he has a very low battery on his Nokia (one of the old square ones), and decides to call a helpline to guide him back to civilization.

On the other side of the call, a seemingly nice young lady picks up, and begins to guide him. I remember a scene where she guided him to a crossroads, where one of the road signs was obscured by foliage. He then pulled it aside to reveal a hidden road.

At the end of the movie, it turns out that the woman wasn't actually helping him, but was instead luring him in to a trap, where he was ambushed by multiple men. I believe the movie ended with a black screen and a white message warning the viewers of not trusting strangers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Lost (2004) - Movie Poster]

**Lost** (2004)

Before anyone starts getting any ideas, no, this one features that guy from the Lois & Clark TV series :-) The movie's [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_%282004_film%29) page gives away most of the plot - so you can confirm it.

Here's the [trailer](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xs6bxe_lost-trailer_shortfilms). You could google for more vids.

Comment: Ye I'd say this is it. First thing came to my mind.